# Read a socket connection in php

Tags: php, sockets, connection

After i create a socket connection using `socket_create()`,`socket_bind()` and send a message to another port of my machine how to read the message that i have send? for example:

```
$address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 4000;
$dest_address = '127.0.0.1';
$dest_port = 4027;
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
socket_bind($sock, $address, $port);
$msg = "Ping !";  
socket_sendto($sock, $msg, strlen($msg), 0, $dest_address, $dest_port);
socket_close($sock);
```

after this do i need to do the following?

```
$sockread = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
socket_bind($sockread, $address, $dest_port);
socket_listen($sockread);
```

Sorry if my question is irrelevant, I am new to sockets connections.

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of socket_sento is [socket_recvfrom](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recvfrom.php).